# My ArcGIS Pro attribute rule to update facilityids sequentially is not working

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcade, attribute-rules

I have a featureclass with the field "FACILITYID". There are values in it that go up to P-72340. I am trying to create an attribute rule so that each time a feature is inserted, the FACILTYID field increases the max FACILITYID value by 10. In this case, the next feature would be P-72350, P-72360 and so on. Here is my code so far:

```
if (isempty($feature.FACILITYID)){
var vals = FeatureSetByName($datastore, "storm_pipes", ['FACILITYID'], false);
var pipevals = Filter(vals, "FACILITYID LIKE 'P-%'");  // filter to only apply to specific features
var numarray = [];

// Loop through features in pipevals
for (var feature in pipevals){
    // Extract the numeric part after removing 'P-' and convert to a number
    var nn = Number(Replace(feature.FACILITYID, 'P-', ''));
    
    // Check if nn is a valid number (not NaN)
    if (!isNaN(nn)) {
        // Push the numeric value into numarray
        Push(numarray, nn);
    }
}

// Check if there are valid numeric values in numarray
if (Count(numarray) > 2){
    // Find the maximum numeric value in numarray
    var maxnum = Max(numarray);

    // Add 10 to the maximum and pad with zeros
    var newNum = maxnum + 10;
    var paddedNum = Text(newNum, '00000');

    // Generate a new FACILITYID
    var maxtext = Concatenate(['P-', paddedNum]);

    // Return the new FACILITYID
    return maxtext;
}
else {
    // If no existing features found, return a default value 'P-00001'
    return 'P-00001';  // You can adjust this as needed
}
```

}

The problem is, it keeps returning P-00010, as if the max value of this feature set is P-00000 at all times. Where am I going wrong?

Here are a few lines of the attribute table:
[image: attributetable]

Comment: Can you provide a line of our attribute table?

Comment: @Xeppit yes, added!